# Trouble converting a file to a dictionary in python

Tags: python

I have a file that has two columns with country names and their capitals. I'm having issues on the capitals that have spaces in their name.
My file that I'm trying to convert to a dictionary looks like

```
Afghanistan         Kabul
Albania             Tirana
Algeria             Algiers
Andorra             Andorra la Vella
```

The code I am using is

```
countries_dict = {}
countries_file = open("countrieslist.txt")
for line in countries_file:
    key, value = line.split()
    countries_dict[key] = value

print(countries_dict)
```

When I run the code I get the following error - ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
I found that when I removed Andorra and its Capital it fixed the issue, but I need a way for it to include the capitals with spaces in them. So that I would get a dictionary like that looked like
`{'Afghanistan': 'Khabul', 'Albania': 'Tirana', 'Algeria': 'Algiers', 'Andorra': 'Andorra la Vella'}`

Comment: This technique and data format won't work well. There are countries with multiple words and capitals with multiple words. Consider changing the format to something better. Or parse it based on countries beginning at column 1 and capitals beginning at column N (fixed). Or use some separator that's not in any name e.g. colon or ##. Or just use CSV, with quoted text.

Answer (score 2):

The file appears to be a fixed-width file, so divide the line on fixed columns. Note that countries could have spaces in the name, too:

countrieslist.txt:

```
Afghanistan         Kabul
Albania             Tirana
Algeria             Algiers
Andorra             Andorra la Vella
The Netherlands     Amsterdam
```

```py
with open('countrieslist.txt') as countries_file:
    countries_dict = {}
    for line in countries_file:
        key,value = line[:20],line[20:]
        countries_dict[key.rstrip()] = value.rstrip()
print(countries_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'Afghanistan': 'Kabul', 'Albania': 'Tirana', 'Algeria': 'Algiers', 'Andorra': 'Andorra la Vella', 'The Netherlands': 'Amsterdam'}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `str.split` can take an argument `maxsplit` that you can specify as `maxsplit=1` in this case so you get the name as the country as the first part and capital as the second, even if the capital itself contains spaces.

```
>>> line = 'Andorra             Andorra la Vella'
>>> line.split()
['Andorra', 'Andorra', 'la', 'Vella']
>>> line.split(maxsplit=1)
['Andorra', 'Andorra la Vella']
```

This of course doesn't solve the problem if the country name itself contains spaces (e.g. `'United Arab Emirates'`). The other option is to use a different character as your delimiter so its not ambiguous if a space character is dividing columns or words. For example if the columns were tab delimited you could use

```
key, value = line.split('\t')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a well-formed data format so you have to do some hacking based on observation. Since both countries and cities can have spaces in their names, a simple split isn't going to work. But what about those spaces in between? If there are at least 2 of them, you've got what you need. Use a regular expression that splits on 2 or more spaces.

```
import re
countries_dict = {}
countries_file = open("countrieslist.txt")
for line in countries_file:
    try:
        key, value = re.split(" {2,}", line.strip())
    except TypeError:
        raise ValueError(f"Malformed data must have 2 spaces between names: {line.strip()}")
    countries_dict[key] = value

print(countries_dict)
```

This could be shortened to

```
countries_dict = dict(re.split(" {2,}", line.strip())
        for line in print(countries_dict)
```